# non resident of Canada , taxes due on sale of shares in Canada

Tags: taxes, canada, capital-gains-tax, non-resident, european-union

I am a resident of a EU country with a double tax treaty with Canada. I pay dividends at source on shares I own in a Canadian bank. What happens when I sell the shares, am I taxed on any gains in Canada or the Eu country?